# send commands to arduino from c++ code in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arduino

I installed arduino IDE on ubuntu, and I writing c++ code. I want to send command to arduino which is connected on serial port 'ttyACM0'.

what are the steps to do that?? is there a library I can use to communicate between C++ code and arduino??

Comment: Generally a decent C example targeting the serial API should work in C++ as well, so have a look here and elsewhere for similar solutions.  While not re-inventing the wheel is great, some here may react poorly to your mention of seeking an existing library as a possible means of solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is there a tutorial in C ??

Answer (score 1):

You can open the serial console window from within the Arduino IDE to send command to the arduino. You can do this by clicking on the right hand side button on the toolbar:

[image: serial console]

There you can communicate with the code you've written using the Arduino IDE.

To implement the serial communication, you shall examples in the Arduino IDE file menu.

If, like me and many other nerds, you like to use the commandline, you can use:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 57600
```

(and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to exit)

or miniterm:

```
python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyACM0 57600
```

(and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to exit).

For both, note that `57600` is the speed you open the port with using `Serial.begin(57600);`

Comment: 57600 is the baud rate, and it can be as low as 9600, the terminal in the Arduino IDE only support a few baud rates but its more than enough choice.

Comment: indeed, 57600 is only an example which is quite commonly used.

Comment: As OP seems to be a beginner, and that you've only explained how to send data, instead of also explaining the code for the Arduino reading the data, a link to the Arduino's Serial library would give more detail.